# How do I handle these two capital sigma?

Tags: statistics, least-squares

I have a question about the least-squares estimator from basic econometrics by Gujarati. It claims that Formula B could be easily and directly verified from Formula A.

Formula A : $K_i=\frac{x_i}{∑(xi)^2}$

Formula B : $∑(K_i)^2=\frac{1}{∑(X_i)^2}$

The symbol is Capital Sigma for summation. I just can't get to the point.

Comment: Are you multiplying $K$ with $i$, the imaginary number?

Comment: How are $X$ and $x$ related?

Comment: Is $i$ a summation index?

Comment: It's all been corrected according to the book. And I think the answer Gribouillis gave may perfectly referring to what Gujarati thought about this formula and the process of deduction-----"These properties can be directly verified from the definition of $k_i$",LOL. I just complicated far from the earth. Anyway, Thanks guys.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche It's the $K_i$. It's not the multiplication.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I'm not quite sure of what "summation index" mean but I guess $i$ may refer to the ordinal of a sequence of a summation. Sorry for the Totally Rookie Style. I'm just starting my math tour on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue comes from an ambiguous phrasing:
$$K_i = \frac{X_i}{\sum_i X_i^2}$$
is poorly written because the same index $i$ is used in the numerator and in the summation below it. The same symbol must not be used in the same formula for two different things so it should be written
$$K_i = \frac{X_i}{\sum_j X_j^2}$$

Notice that the denominator is a constant number $d = \sum_j X_j^2$, it does not depend on $i$, hence
$$\sum_i K_i^2 = \sum_i \left(\frac{X_i}{d}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{d^2}\sum_i X_i^2 = \frac{1}{d^2} \times d = \frac{1}{d} = \frac{1}{\sum_j X_j^2}$$